# Haar Object Detection patent issue

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, face-detection, feature-detection

I would like to know if all of the Haar Object Detection Api (Python) in OpenCV patent protected?  As I understand it SIFT, SURF, & Haar Cascade are patented, but I am not really clear as to what that means with regard to all of the Haar Object Detection Api.

If it is indeed patent protected, what are some viable alternatives for object detection (namely human anatomy)?

Answer (score 0):

API's by themselves can not be patented.  It amounts to merely code.  However, API's used in a process/machine/method/etc. can be part of a patent, but only because the API was used to manipulate data in some way.  Instead, API's can be copyrighted (like a book or song).

Answer (score 0):

The Haar wavelet object detector in OpenCV is not patented.

> Viola and Jones had patented their algorithm. So in order to use it commercially, you would have to license if from the authors, possibly paying a fee. As a way to extend the detector, Dr. Rainer Lienhart, the original implementer of the OpenCV Haar feature detector, proposed adding two new types of features and transforming each weak learner into a tree. This later trick, besides helping in the classification, was also sufficient to get out of the patent protection of the original method.

See [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441226/Haar-feature-Object-Detection-in-Csharp)

The only patented algorithms in openCV that cannot be used for commercial use are SIFT and SURF. See [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/19659/patent-face-recognition/)